# pandas styling single cell

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I'm creating the following Dataframe and trying to change the backgroud of my 'code' cell from my last row when its length its different to 8 but I dont get wherer I'm wrong...

```
def add_warn_color():
    return 'background-color: yellow'

    
def validate_data(row):        
    if len(row['code']) != 8:
        row['code'].style.applymap(add_warn_color)


data = {0: ['title1','ABC123ZX'], 1: ['title2', '9876QWERTYUI']}
df = pd.DataFrame().from_dict(data,orient='index',columns=['title','code'])
row = df.iloc[-1:,:]
validate_data(row)
```

I'm pretty sure I'm missunderstanding something but I don't get it...

Comment: You don't have a column called `'job'` In this example which values should be yellow?

Comment: Sorry, my bad, those 'jobs' columns are the 'code' columns. Gonna edit the question right now ^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only DataFrame (not Series) has the .style attribute. We need to use the columnwise style and apply the style to the cell in question. Note that the style is only applied to the returned styler.

```
def warning_colors(s):
    # Mask: Is it the last row. Is the length != 8?
    warn = (s.reset_index().index == len(s) - 1) & (s.str.len() != 8)
    return ['background-color: yellow' if v else '' for v in warn]

data = {0: ['title1','ABC123ZX'], 1: ['title2', '9876QWERTYUI']}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data, orient='index', columns=['title','code'])

# Style only the 'code' column
dfs = df.style.apply(warning_colors, subset='code')
dfs
```

|  | title | code |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | title1 | ABC123ZX |
| 1 | title2 | /* Yellow */ 9876QWERTYUI |